# How to Convert Equations of Motion from Cylindrical to Custom Coordinates for a Cylindrical Shell?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have derived the equations of motion for a cylindrical shell using cylindrical coordinates. However, I would like to switch to a specific coordinate system that is commonly used in mechanical engineering literature. This system is defined on the middle surface of the cylindrical shell and is usually denoted by $ξ_1, ξ_2, ξ_3$
(as shown in the image below).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWhH.png)

Is there a straightforward way to transform the equations from the cylindrical coordinate system to this $ξ_1,ξ_2,ξ_3$ system? Or do I need to derive all the internal and external forces from scratch to rewrite the equations in the new coordinate system?